# Connect Cannon PIXMA MP499 wirelessly with Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have a Cannon PIXMA MP499 all in one printer and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to wirelessly connect to my laptop. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. It connects fine via USB but I would like to utilize the wireless feature so I don't have to keep plugging in every time I want to print.  Any suggestions?

Comment: See if any of the answers here are helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/469241/how-do-i-setup-a-wi-fi-printer/525038#525038